# Hide/Show div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Note questions that have already been posted does not solves my problem. The above are the displays from my side menu bar, I want when the user click on a link its content are displayed on the same page and the other div content are hidden. I tried the codes below but they seem not working.

```js
 $('a.common').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $(id).fadeIn('slow', function() {
     // Animation complete
   });
 });
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="canvas">

    <div id="nav">
      <h2 id="title">
  <i class="fa fa-sitemap">
      </i> MENU</h2>
      <ul id="toggle">

        <li>
          <div class="active border">
            <a href="#div1" class="common">HOME</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <span class="menu-icons  fa fa-user"></span> 
            <a href="#div2" class="common">ABOUT US</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>

            <a href="#div3" class="common">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-nav" id="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>


      <div id="div1">TEST ONE</div>

      <div id="div2">TEST TWO</div>

      <div id="div3">TEST THREE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't see abutton class in your html.

Comment: class name changed. check code again

Comment: div with id div3 is already visible. do you want to fadeIn to visible div?

Comment: The above code does not hide my divs on click

Comment: side note: consider to change `click()` with `on('click', function(){})` and `fadeIn()` with `show('slow', function(){})`

Comment: You have missed closing `</div>`  after portfolio in `<li>`

Comment: Even though not working

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that you had $('a.button') instead of $('a.common')
You also want a css to hide the divs at the beginning.
And also when you fade in a new div, you need to hide the current one.

```js
$('a.common').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $("#divs div").hide();
   $(id).fadeIn('slow', function() {
     // Animation complete
   });
 });
```

```css
#divs div {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="canvas">

    <div id="nav">
      <h2 id="title">
  <i class="fa fa-sitemap">
      </i> MENU</h2>
      <ul id="toggle">

        <li>
          <div class="active border">
            <a href="#div1" class="common">HOME</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <span class="menu-icons  fa fa-user"></span> 
            <a href="#div2" class="common">ABOUT US</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>

            <a href="#div3" class="common">PORTFOLIO</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-nav" id="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>


      <div id="divs">
        <div id="div1">TEST ONE</div>

        <div id="div2">TEST TWO</div>

        <div id="div3">TEST THREE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean not hiding? Click on ABOUT US, you'll see: TEST TWO, then click on PORTFOLIO, and you'll see now only TEST THREE, because TEST TWO was hidden.

Comment: I don't know may be something wring in my code - it is not working here

Comment: What do you mean here? HERE in StackOverflow, just 10cm above this line you have a blue button: "Run code snippet", click on it and you'll see. If not then restart your computer or at least your browser

Comment: If you temper with the working code without understanding it, don't be surprised that you break it... OR adjust the line $("#divs div").hide(); accordingly

Comment: Mr Gavriel your codes are simple its not a question of understanding or not here. What i meant by 'here' is that my menu have other jquery effects which maybe a reason why your codes are not working on script

Comment: @Nia, maybe, but I can only work with the code you published in stackoverflow, I can't read minds or code on your local computer, sorry. This snippet solves the problem in your question. For other problems you're welcome to open other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your jQuery selector:

```
//This ona means that you  are searching for tag a with class button
$('a.abutton').click(function() {})

//You should use:
$('a.common').click(function() {})

// Because your a tags has class 'common'
```

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 problem

1. Your `<div>` tag is not closed properly in your `<li>`
2. Initially you are not hiding your div so it can be fade in once you click on it.

Here is the fiddle for your code https://jsfiddle.net/2tkfq87o/

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your html had an error. On `<div>` element was not added. Secondly you never called hide() on all the divs at the start because of which none of them were hidden. You had only fadeIn. If all divs are visible, it makes no sense to call fadeIn.

So hide them first. Then call fadeIn on click and at the same time hide the div present already.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.common').click(function() {
    hideAllDivs();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      // Animation complete
    });
  });

  var hideAllDivs = function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
  }
  hideAllDivs();
  $('#div1').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="canvas">

    <div id="nav">
      <h2 id="title">
  <i class="fa fa-sitemap">
      </i> MENU</h2>
      <ul id="toggle">

        <li>
          <div class="active border">
            <a href="#div1" class="common">HOME</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <span class="menu-icons  fa fa-user"></span> 
            <a href="#div2" class="common">ABOUT US</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>

            <a href="#div3" class="common">PORTFOLIO</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav" id="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>


    <div id="div1">TEST ONE</div>

    <div id="div2">TEST TWO</div>

    <div id="div3">TEST THREE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```